# Get max width/height if orientation can change

Tags: javascript, android, ios, orientation, resolution

I'm trying to get the maximum screen width the user may have their browser at. For desktop this is easy:

```
var screenMax = window.screen.availWidth | window.screen.width;
```

However on tablets and smartphones, the user may begin in portrait mode then change orientation to landscape, at which point the width will increase. I know there are ways to listen for orientation change like so:

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
}, false);
```

But this is no good to me. I need to know if the user is able to change orientation and therefore get the highest number out of the height or width like so:

```
var screenMax = Math.max(window.screen.availWidth | window.screen.width, window.screen.availHeight | window.screen.height);
```

But this is no good for desktop because the height may be larger than the width (probably quite rare though), but the orientation will never change.

Is there a solution that fits all?

Comment: just consider user is **always** able to change orientation. On desktop user can change the size of the window as well as change orientation on the mobile.

Comment: I've taken `window.screen.width` to account for this already on desktop. No matter what size they've scaled their browser to, this value will be the maximum screen size.